# Is it possible to re-enter the Joker's factory to get the Titan canister?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

After getting drugged by Joker and being sent on the Mr. Freeze mission is it possible to re-enter the Joker's factory to get the Titan canister inside.  I've not been able to find a re-entry point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first time you enter the Steel Mill, you go in via an upper entrance and down into the smelter.  The second time, you enter through a back door near the water.

Once you've completed the second pass through the Steel Mill, you can re-enter through this door as many times as you like, but you'll probably have to fight the guards outside again.  Further, it's kind of a long trek through the factory to find most of the stuff inside. (especially getting back to the arena you fight in early in your first trip)

Luckily, the Titan canister is near the entrance.  However, if you're going back through to collect all the trophies, I'd recommend waiting until you have all the gadgets so that you only have to make this trip once.

This video is a little shaky, but it shows a picture of the map, so you can see the area of the map you need to get to in order to find this door:

Comment: Thanks agent86! Spent a while looking around and didn't find the back door.

Comment: You can also re-enter the Steel Mill through the hole in the roof you exit the Steel Mill through the second time. It's hard to spot, but it's definitely there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact, the game has been carefully designed so that it's impossible to permanently miss any collectibles. There is always some way you can collect it later.

In the case of the factory, you will be required to re-visit it at a later point in the story, and after that it will remain open so that you can return to get anything you missed the first time.